# how to sort HTML table data based on two columns

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML table like these

HTML table output like these:

```
Work Order  PROCESS_ID_D.PROCESS_ID_H   Mar 2013    Apr 2013
V100224     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
A100225     $1.00                       $0.00       $819,250.90
A100225     $0.00                       $703,648.70 $753,909.31
Z100123     $1.00                       $0.00       $0.00
D100358     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
Z100123     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
```

After sorting HTML table data  like these:

```
Work Order  PROCESS_ID_D.PROCESS_ID_H   Mar 2013    Apr 2013
A100225     $1.00                       $0.00       $819,250.90
A100225     $0.00                       $703,648.70 $753,909.31
D100358     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
V100224     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
Z100123     $1.00                       $0.00       $0.00
Z100123     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
```

Excepting result will be result like these:

```
Work Order  PROCESS_ID_D.PROCESS_ID_H   Mar 2013    Apr 2013
A100225     $0.00                       $703,648.70 $753,909.31
A100225     $1.00                       $0.00       $819,250.90
V100224     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
D100358     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
Z100123     $0.00                       $0.00       $0.00
Z100123     $1.00                       $0.00       $0.00
```

My requirement is based on  Work Order column and   PROCESS_ID_D.PROCESS_ID_H column to be sorted their is no  click action its default sorted. Please help me these.

[Please check code here](http://jsfiddle.net/panabakavenkatesh/fouLmvdu/3/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the values of the two columns you want to order by:

```
var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(0)').text() + $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text();
var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(0)').text() + $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text();

return (tda > tdb) ? 1 : (tda < tdb) ? -1 : 0;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lghgfdu/1/